# MS Access DoCmd.GoToRecord ,,AcNewRecord is not working on bounded form with the query in which we are pulling the data from SQL View

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I have a Query in MS Access which is loading the data from the SQL view, that query is bounded to the form and on the form load event I have written Docmd.GoToRecord ,, acNewRecord. but it is showing error message that "you can't go to specified record".

Comment: Is the form editable at all? Can you edit and append records directly in the query? If no, the linked View may be missing a Primary Key.

Comment: Form is editable but the recordsource for this form is a SQL view.